# Convert String into java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, time, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I want to convert elements of an array list into `ZonedDateTime` object after parsing them. A string is shown below.

```
"2017-02-12 06:59:00 +1300"
```

At the moment I use the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter =
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ");
```

And try to use `parse`, to get the time:

```
this.actionTime = dateTimeFormatter.parse(actionTime, ZonedDateTime::from);
```

See below method:

```
public DateCalculatorTest(String actionTime, int expectedDayOfWeek) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = 
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ");
    DateTimeFormatter localTimeFormatter = 
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
    this.actionTime = dateTimeFormatter.parse(actionTime, ZonedDateTime::from);
    this.expectedDayOfWeek = expectedDayOfWeek;
}
```

However, I am not able to parse the string. I get the following error:

```
Text '2017-02-12 06:59:00 +1300' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017, DayOfMonth=12, MonthOfYear=2, OffsetSeconds=46800},ISO resolved to 06:59 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Is there a way to do this with `java.time`?

Comment: I changed `YYYY` (week-based-year) to `yyyy` (year-of-era) and used `System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-02-12 06:59:00 +1300", dateTimeFormatter));` which printed `2017-02-12T06:59+13:00`

Comment: Your string contains an offset (+1300), not a time zone (like Pacific/Fakaofo), so it would really be more correct and also somehow simpler to parse it into an `OffsetDateTime` rather than a `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this using the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ");
DateTimeFormatter localTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
this.symbol = symbol;
this.actionTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(actionTime, dateTimeFormatter);
this.actionDate = LocalDate.parse(expectedResult, localTimeFormatter);
```

Answer (score 5):

In the `DateTimeFormatter` years should be small letters. Replace

```
 YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ
```

with

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ
```

And you don't require two ZZ, single is enough. In your code the `ZoneId` instance will give you default `ZoneId`. It will fall back to `LocalDateTime`. If you want to specify the `ZoneId` use the following

```
this.actionTime =  ZonedDateTime.parse(actionTime, dateTimeFormatter.withZone(ZoneId.of(<<yourxoneid>>)));
```